# Jquery fancybox with gallery thumbnail list in c# asp.net website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I'm using the [Jquery Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to display a gallery of images in a c# asp.net website.
Now I have to do a modification on the lightbox, so that in addition to show the clicked thumbnail in the lightbox, I have to show the list of the thumbnails of the gallery also in the lightbox that appears when I click on an image, just below the displayed image, and when I click on a thumbnail, the large version is showed.

I was looking for the solution in the [api](http://fancybox.net/api) but I couldn't understand how to do this.

Here is the code I use to display the images on the page.

```
 foreach image {
 <li>
    <a href="<%= image.GetVariantFilePath("Large") %>" title="<%= image.Description %>" rel="imgGallery">
        <img src="<%= image.GetVariantFilePath("Small") %>" alt="<%= image.Description %>" />
    </a>
 </li>
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) can do what you're looking for. Check out the Slideshow image gallery demos, it has thumbnails inside the lightbox. It's not Fancybox, which you're already using, but from what I can see Fancybox doesn't have any options like that out of the box (PrettyPhoto is the only one I'm aware of that does).